# Cells overlapping in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, urlrequest

I am displaying the results of a web request to a custom API in an UICollectionView with dynamically sized cells. However, when I call reloadSections after having fetched the data, many of the cells display overlapping.

[image: overlap cells]

As the view is scrolled, the cells display in their proper place.

I have tracked down the error to calling reloadSections in the completion block for my web request. Using hardcoded text, the collection view displays properly with the initial layout. If reloadSections is called in the completion block, the error occurs. Below is the relevant code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "ExhibitionsCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ExhibitionsCollectionViewCell")
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)

    collectionView.dataSource = exhibitionsDataSource
    collectionView.delegate = self

    store.fetchExhibitions {
        (exhibitionsResult) -> Void in

        switch exhibitionsResult {
        case let .success(exhibitions):
            print("Successfully found \(exhibitions.count) exhibitions.")
            if exhibitions.first != nil {
                self.exhibitionsDataSource.exhibitions = exhibitions
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            print("Error fetching exhibitions: \(error)")
            self.exhibitionsDataSource.exhibitions.removeAll()
        }
        // this is the line that produces the erroneous layout
        self.collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0))
    }

}
```

Code making the web request:

```
func fetchExhibitions(completion: @escaping (ExhibitionsResult) -> Void) {

    let url = WebAPI.exhibitionsURL
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let result = self.processExhibitionsRequest(data: data, error: error)
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            completion(result)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

If there is any other code that would be helpful in answering this question, let me know.

**Update:** I fixed the issue by implementing the following delegate method of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    let height = cell?.contentView.bounds.height ?? 1
    let width = cell?.contentView.bounds.width ?? 1


    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

**Update2:** Upon switching out my fake Lorem Ipsum data for the data actually retrieved from the server the problem resurfaced. However, I was able to finally solve the issue simply by switching the line

```
self.collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0))
```

to

```
self.reloadData()
```

I would think that reloadSection(_:) simply performs the same action as reloadData() but for the selected sections and the documentation doesn't seem to indicate otherwise...but either way it works now!

Comment: Carefully go after literally everything that affects the size. Cell xib, flow layout, container Xib, width/height, edge insets. If not that, become familiar with the queue and recycle functions PrepareForReuse(). The fact autolayout calculates just before placement. Animation timings (0.25 second default). Size of Xibs in XCode vs the phone differences (Does it layout differently on different phone/pad sizes)? They will all give you guidelines on where to narrow this down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that code I'm not sure of the reason, but maybe try to implement some of the functions provided by the delegate **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**.

Focus on the function

> sizeForItemAtIndexPath

Example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(320, 500);
    }
```

Comment: This does appear to solve my issue! I had assumed since I was using autolayout and self-sizing cells I wouldn't need to implement this method, but that assumption appears wrong.

Comment: While this did fix my initial issue, it did not ultimately solve the problem at hand. I had to change the function to reload the data upon retrieving it from the server.